# is there a PEAR::DB equivilent of FROM_UNIXTIME()

Tags: pear

I'm working on a way to extract given data from a timestamp in a MySQL. I've been advised to try FROM_UNIXTIME() ... but my development is built around pear::db so I'm looking for a replacement. Have you any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a PHP-based solution instead of using SQL? Just use the `date()` function to format your timestamp:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
```

**Specific answer  (see comments):** to get just the month from this, just change the format string to "m" and leave out everything else.

Comment: no i've been advised to try the following - but it's a mysql function SELECT * FROM database WHERE MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(timestamp)) = 1

Comment: So it looks like what you're looking for is a replacement for the MONTH() function, not the FROM_UNIXTIME() function... which is what my answer gives you.

Comment: I'm learning about timestamps. I can find lots of infomation about extracting data from current timestamps but little about querying a database timestamp (e.g. from the timestamp field return all records from jan)

Comment: You'll need to be more clear about what you're trying to do then. Are you asking for something that doesn't use database functions like FROM_UNIXTIME()? Are you trying to select records from one January (e.g. 2009), or all Januarys, regardless of year?